# Android Preferences Layout

Tags: android, preferences, checkboxpreference

I am using CheckBoxPreference in my preferences activity.

The application is written in hebrew, which is RTL language.

Does anyone knows if I can change the direction of the CheckBoxPreference, so that the checkbox will be on the left and the text will be aligned to the right?

10X,
Udi

Answer (score 0):

You need to extend "CheckBoxPreference" base class and override the onCreateView method adding your own layout.